# How to get the count of excluded nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes like this. 
[image]

I want to get all the nodes(from c1 to c5) which are not mapped to node (l1), so my result nodes should be (c2),(c4) and (c5). How can query in Neo4j.

Comment: Are the c nodes all of the same label? And if so, are you looking for ALL nodes of that label that are not linked to l1, or just this particular subset?

Comment: Also, can you provide a textual representation of your data? From your drawing, it looks like there might be 2 "l1" nodes. It is also not clear what you wrote in the rightmost node.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose those nodes from which there is no one-way path to the desired node:

```
MATCH (E {name: 'l1'}) WITH E
MATCH (M) WHERE NOT (M)-[*]->(E)
RETURN M
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution would be (C, L are node labels R1 is relationship type)

```
MATCH (c:C)
WHERE NOT((c)-[:R1]->(l:L {...})
RETURN c
```

where `(l:L {...})` is some filter to identify node l1.

If there is a high number of relationships coming out of C nodes that would become slow. You could try following:

```
MATCH (l:L {...})<-[:R1]-(c:C)
WITH COLLECT(c) AS cs
MATCH (c2:C)
WHERE NOT c2 NOT cs
RETURN c2
```

You should choose between the two based on your data.